# validar varios input que su valor sea mayor que 10 (mask)

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un formulario con muchos inputs para ingresar telefono, en todos su valor debe tener 10 digitos estoy usando una maskara y le agregue una clase validarTelefonos a todos los input para telefono , no se por que me imprime 16 o 1 en el console.

```
    $('.validarTelefonos').change(function(){
        var tel = $(".validarTelefonos").val().match( /\d+/g);
      if( tel.length != 10  ){
        console.log( ($('#telefonoParticular').val().length) );
        $('#mensaje').addClass('btn btn-danger').html('El telefono debe tener 10 digitos').show();
        return false;
      } else{
        $('#mensaje').removeClass('btn btn-danger').html('').hide();
      }
    });
```

maskara

```
data-inputmask=""mask": "(99) 99-99-99-99""
```

miren ya va quedando pero me falta el each por lo que pienso

```
            $('.validarTelefonos').change(function(){
            var tel = $(".validarTelefonos").val().match( /\d+/g);
            tel = tel.join("");
          if( tel.length != 10 ){
            console.log( ($('#telefonoParticular').val().length) );
            $('#mensaje').addClass('btn btn-danger').html('El telefono debe tener 10 digitos').show();
            return false;
          } else{
            $('#mensaje').removeClass('btn btn-danger').html('').hide();
          }
        });
```

Comment: Saludos hermano Carlos, ¿Podrías agregar la máscara que estás usando por favor?

Comment: así* creo que me no me dejé entender, me refería al formato de la máscara que estás usando :D

Comment: Este resultado es el que no me convence tel.length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solucion

Bueno así quedó; gracias por ayudarme le agregué el **each** para recorrer todos los elementos que tengan la clase `validarTelefonos`

```
$('.validarTelefonos').change(function(){
  $(".validarTelefonos").each(function(){
     var tel = $(this).val().match( /\d+/g);
     tel = tel.join("");
     if( tel.length != 10 ){
        $('#mensaje').addClass('btn btn-danger').html('El telefono debe tener 10 digitos').show();
        return false;
        } else{
        $('#mensaje').removeClass('btn btn-danger').html('').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

## Explicación en los comentarios:

```
data-inputmask=""mask": "(99) 99-99-99-99""
//2 paréntesis       +
//3 guiones          +
//1 espacio en blanco 
//--------------------  
//6 caracteres extra
//Por lo tanto, tienes 10 dígitos + 6 caracteres extras:
//hace un total de 16 caracteres a imprimir.
```

## Dato curioso:

En la siguiente línea siempre estás preguntando por el valor de 1 campo en particular.

```
console.log( ($('#telefonoParticular').val().length) );
```

## Detalle importante:

Cuando se utiliza una máscara de jQuery, ese formato ocupa espacio "lenght" en la cadena donde se va a utilizar.

## Solución:

Reemplaza:

```
if( tel.length != 10  ){
```

Por:

```
if( tel.length != 16 ){
```

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74074/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-carlos-enrique-gil-gil).

Comment: bro, elimina los comentarios para que el sitio se mantenga ordenadito y bien presentable, seguimos la conversación en el chat :D (enlace en el comentario anterior)